# How to obfuscate my project using ProGuard tool?

Tags: android, proguard

I am wondering about how to obfuscate the Android application using ProGuard tool.
I've read info from http://android-sdk.appspot.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html.

But no luck still. I've set to enable configuration for ProGuard tool in default.properties file added following line:

proguard.config=proguard.cfg

Then build the project. And was looking to generate "mapping.txt". But not generated.

Can you suggest me where I am wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard is only integrated in the Android build process as of the Android 2.2 SDK. You may have to update to the latest SDK and then update the project with "android update project".

Furthermore, ProGuard is only applied in release builds: "ant release".

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard only runs when making external builds, not internal development builds. Use File->Export->Android->Export Android Application

Answer (score 0):

Your doing nothing wrong. In addition to setting the config file as you indicated you might also need to set debuggable=false in the android manifest.